# Naguère et Jadis dans la langue orale

Tags: oral

Quelqu'un peut-il me préciser la fréquence d'utilisation des mots *Naguère* et *Jadis.*

N'ayant jamais entendu ces mots dans la langue orale, j'ai peur de me ridiculiser si je les utilise entre amis.

Ce sont juste des mots qu'on trouve dans les livres, ou on peut les utiliser entre copains ? Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 3):

La fréquence d'utilisation spontanée des mots *naguère* et *jadis* dans les conversations *entre copains* doit être extrêmement proche de zéro, voire en dessous ;-) Il s'agit de vocabulaire beaucoup trop soutenu.

Si les copains en question sont membres de l'Académie française, la fréquence sera significative, mais je doute que ce soit le style de *conversation entre copains* que tu avais en tête.

Answer (score 1):

Ces mots me semblent en effet peu fréquents dans la langue de la conversation. Il n'est pas impossible d'utiliser, de façon isolée, une tournure un peu littéraire dans la conversation, mais cela attire fortement l'attention.

Cela étant dit, l'expression *de naguère* me semble moins déplacée dans la conversation que l'utilisation de *naguère* en tant qu'adverbe.

Notons que dans la langue soutenue, *naguère* signifie "récemment", tandis que *jadis* signifie "il y a longtemps". L'utilisation de *naguère* avec le sens "jadis, autrefois" est courante mais critiquée.

Answer (score 1):

En gros, ces mots ne sont pas utilisés à l'oral (en France en tout cas), à moins de vouloir, humoristiquement ou poétiquement, donner un aspect très désuet et littéraire à la phrase.

A l'oral, on utilisera :

- avant
- dans le temps
- à l'époque/ à cette époque là

ou classiquement, des expressions plus précises comme :

- avant guerre
- dans les années XX

Answer (score 0):

Peu fréquent, naguère pour dire jamais et jadis pour dire auparavant.